# Why can't I connect to a remote SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2014

I have tried the various suggestions on this issue and am still having no luck.  I am trying to use SQL Server Management Studio 2014 to connect to a remote SQL Server instance.  The server is there.  I can ping it, connect via TELNET to port 1433, I can TRACEROUTE it.  But when I use SSMS to try to connect, using a name *or* IP Address, I get the error that the "network path cannot be found."

SQL Server Browser is running, and I even turned off Windows Firewall thinking maybe that was the culprit.  I still am not having any luck.  I tried using Visual Studio to connect, with no luck there, either.

I have run out of options, having read what's been posted as fixes.  Anyone have any *other* ideas?

Comment: verity that SQL server is running on port 1433

Comment: It is.  Other people can connect.  It seems to be just me.

Comment: any difference between your machine and others ? Both on the same network ?

Comment: No, I'm working from my home, and they're just friends who tried from their homes.  I have no other connectivity issues, so I can't get a grip on what the problem is.